# Seaborn custom axis sxale: matplotlib.scale.FuncScale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to figure out how to get a custom scale for my axis. My x-axis goes from 0 to 1,000,000 in 100,000 step increments, but I want to scale each of these numbers by 1/100, so that they go from 0 to 1,000 in 100 step increments. `matplotlib.scale.FuncScale`, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here's what the plot currently looks like:

[image: current output]

My code looks like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataPlot = pd.DataFrame({"plot1" : [1, 2, 3], "plot2" : [4, 5, 6], "plot3" : [7, 8, 9]})
ax = sns.lineplot(data = dataPlot, dashes = False, palette = ["blue", "red", "green"])
ax.set_xlim(1, numRows)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, numRows, 100000))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.scale.FuncScale("xaxis", ((lambda x : x / 1000), (lambda y : y * 1000)))
```

When I run this code specifically, I get `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'scale'`, so I tried adding `import matplotlib as mpl` to the top of the code and then changing the last line to be `mpl.scale.FuncScale("xaxis", ((lambda x : x / 1000), (lambda y : y * 1000)))` and that actually ran without error, but but it didn't change anything.

How can I get this to properly scale the axis?

Comment: Is scaling the x-axis data by `1/100` and then plot an option?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using a DataFrame, which, to my knowledge, means that the index is more or less built-in. I'm not particularly attached to using a DataFrame, though, if you know of a better way data type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification from the question comments a straightforward solution scaling the x-axis data in the dataframe (x-data in the question case being the df index) and then plot.

Using example data since the code from the question wasn't running on its own.
x starting range is `0 to 100`, and then scaled to `0 to 10`, but that's equivalent to any other starting range and scaling.

---

**1st the default df.plot:** (just as reference)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(0, 101, 1) * 1.5

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['y_data'])
print(df)
```

```
     y_data
0       0.0
1       1.5
2       3.0
3       4.5
4       6.0
..      ...
96    144.0
97    145.5
98    147.0
99    148.5
100   150.0
```

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

Note that per default df.plot uses the index as x-axis.

---

**2nd scaling the x-data in the dataframe:**

The interims dfs are only displayed to follow along.

***Preparation***

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Getting the original index data as a column to further work with (see scaling below).

```
     index  y_data
0        0     0.0
1        1     1.5
2        2     3.0
3        3     4.5
4        4     6.0
..     ...     ...
96      96   144.0
97      97   145.5
98      98   147.0
99      99   148.5
100    100   150.0
```

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'index':'x_data'})  # just to be more explicit
```

```
     x_data  y_data
0         0     0.0
1         1     1.5
2         2     3.0
3         3     4.5
4         4     6.0
..      ...     ...
96       96   144.0
97       97   145.5
98       98   147.0
99       99   148.5
100     100   150.0
```

***Scaling***

```
df['x_data'] = df['x_data'].apply(lambda x: x/10)
```

```
     x_data  y_data
0       0.0     0.0
1       0.1     1.5
2       0.2     3.0
3       0.3     4.5
4       0.4     6.0
..      ...     ...
96      9.6   144.0
97      9.7   145.5
98      9.8   147.0
99      9.9   148.5
100    10.0   150.0
```

---

**3rd df.plot with specific columns:**

```
df.plot(x='x_data', y = 'y_data')
```

By `x=` a specific column instead of the default = index is used as the x-axis.

[image]

Note that the y data hasn't changed but the x-axis is now scaled compared to the "1st the default df.plot" above.